# Can we disabled sunday in salesforce datepicker?

Tags: visualforce, date-picker

How disable Sunday in salesforce standard datepicker??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no officially approved way to modify date picker like this. Instead, you could just display an error when the user selects a Sunday, or you could write your own date picker (or use one from jQuery or something).